# If I use EF Code First then how can I add another column to a table?

Tags: entity-framework

I created POCO classes and then EF created the database tables for me when I tried to access the data. This worked without problem. I have now populated my tables with data. Not just seed data but real data.

Now I would like to add another column to a table. I assume the first thing I need to do is to add a field to the POCO class but what's next after that?  I now have my database filled with data. On the SQL side I know how to add the column myself but do I have to do something with EF or will it automatically pick up that my column was added to the table and my field to the POCO class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Code First Migrations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh770484(v=vs.103).aspx). It can update your database automatically or not.